# How to start with Custom Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts

**I want to create this CHART**, but i don't know how to start with that.. Because i cant found similar chart and i can't find any way how to create this one..
This graph i create just with **CSS** it's enough for now, but later i wanna receive a live data into chart so via **CSS** it's impossible and the chart is not responsive..

So any advice how to create this chart ?
Using jQuery or another one ?

[image]

Comment: Google for "javascript overlapping circle chart"?

Comment: Use any charting library that has Bubble Chart . This is one : http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bubble